# Validate doctrine entity based on another entity's data

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I want to build an article configurator with symfony2.
In my first entity all possible article configurations are stored.

> Entity PossibleArticleConfiguration
> Name: Article One
> MinLength: 250
> MaxLength: 500
> MinWidth: 250
> MaxWidth: 500

An object in my second entity looks like this:

> Entity
>
> ConfiguredArticle
>
> Name: Article One
>
> Length: 300
>
> Width: 400

Are there any best practices to validate the ConfiguredArticle object based on the min and max range in PossibleArticleConfiguration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a relation like ConfiguredArticle -> PossibleArticleConfiguration ( one-to-many / one-to-tone ) ?

Comment: Yes, there is a relation ConfiguredArticle/Material OneToMany <-> ManyToOne PossibleArticleConfiguration/Material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom constraint. If the two entities are not associated with mappings you can inject the object manager. Callbacks might work too if you have mapped associations for the entities.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

inside the ConfiguredArticle entity you can have methods like:

```
public function isLengthValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)   {
    if ($this->getLength < $this->getArticleConfiguration()->getMinLength()) {
        $context->addViolationAt('length', 'The length does not satisfy the minimum length', array(), null);
    }
    if ($this->getLength > $this->getArticleConfiguration()->getMaxLength()) {
        $context->addViolationAt('length', 'The length does not satisfy the maximum length', array(), null);
    }
}

public function isWidthValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)    {
    if ($this->getWidth < $this->getArticleConfiguration()->getMinWidth()) {
        $context->addViolationAt('width', 'The width does not satisfy the minimum width', array(), null);
    }
    if ($this->getWidth > $this->getArticleConfiguration()->getMaxWidth()) {
        $context->addViolationAt('width', 'The width does not satisfy the maximum width', array(), null);
    }
}
```

Read more on how to use callback methods for validation on this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html